# Javascript code changed/main banner not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this javascript which has a banner showcased on home page. Somehow it stopped working even though i did not change anything in the script. Are the brackets wrong...please help.

```
$( ".container" ).prepend( "<div class='slider'>" + 
    "<img  class='banner_' img src='http://f.7i.no" +
    "/1423011096_indexbanner.png' alt='' /><div " +
    "class='header_slider_box'><a href='/campaign/new' " +
    "class='button'><img src='http://f.7i.no" +
    "/1420827546_1415972362_button_03.png' /></a>" + 
    "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CkJ56vl7uI' " +
    "class='button2'>or Watch our Video</a></div></div>" );
```

If you need css or anything else I will provide. Please help, im trying to fix this problem tonight as i want the site to be up and running tomorrow.

Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/on0aoy2t/ is running fine, no?

Comment: Im really desperate in getting this fixed, please help.

Comment: Terry, no, the banner is not showing up.

Comment: the banner shows 2 kids, right? it's showing up for me.

Comment: Yes, it it not showing up for me. I checked chrome, ie...not showing.

Comment: did you look at my fiddle link? that's not working?

Comment: Not sure what you mean Timmerz. Im pretty new to this...what link. The site is beta.helpinghandcrowd.com. The banner is supposed to show under the header. Under the grey area. This is so frustrating.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/on0aoy2t <- that one, from my comment above.

Comment: I see something that does not make sense to me: `<img  class='banner_' img src= ...`

Comment: Oh, yes, but the create campaign btn and watch video is supposed to be under the headline. It was there before, not sure what ha happened. Seems as the styles are gone too.

Comment: kidkamek, what do you mean?

Comment: My JS console (and probably yours) is actually complaining about the `$("#homepage").append("<...` line, probably because of the stray `"` in the middle of the string (`src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/5CkJ56vl7uI rel=0"'`)

Comment: p.s. [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: That part of the code i mentioned:

which one is the img class? `'banner_img'` or `'banner_'` . If the second then you are declaring an img attribute called 'img' that does not make sense to me.

Comment: You mention the styles are gone... If you could edit your question and put your css maybe we can see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

```
$( ".container" ).prepend( "<div class='slider'>" + 
"<img class='banner_img' src='http://f.7i.no" +
"/1423011096_indexbanner.png' alt='' /><div " +
"class='header_slider_box'><a href='/campaign/new' " +
"class='button'><img src='http://f.7i.no" +
"/1420827546_1415972362_button_03.png' /></a>" + 
"<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CkJ56vl7uI' " +
"class='button2'>or Watch our Video</a></div></div>" );
```

Comment: Jbaczuk: not working, I think one of the reasons may be because the " and ' are not correctly place. Don't you have ' within ". Please write out the code fully without the + on how its supposed to be. I have a hard time to understand all the above. Not a JScript person. I dont understand why you broke up the url for the image.

Comment: @user1804391 It's easier to read than one giant line (for me).  It worked when I tested it, you must have a different problem.  What is your console output?

Comment: Paul Roub: I dont have the double bracket in the code for the youtube url.

Comment: I opened up the console in chrome, where am I supposed to look now. Sorry guys, I have no clue about this language, a dev created this for me and I just got lost when it stopped working. :(

Comment: click on the console tab and then reload the page and see what you get.

Comment: what am I supposed to look at, there are so many things on there. element network sources etc..not sure...

Comment: uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected string  (index 681)

Comment: There can you find that string in your code? Should give you a line number.

Comment: ok, so i fixed it, but the banner now is not 100% width...grr...one thing after another...;(

Comment: .banner_img{
    width:100%;
height: 50%;
}  So it seems the css are right for the 100% stretch, yet its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably should post a new question so it's not a big mess on this one.

Comment: /thank you guys, just reading all the comments I did not see when looking on the same page as  my question. Will get back if I don't understand something. Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: So, can somebody summarize what Im supposed to do to make this work? I am a little confused by all comments. Where should I make changes and what changes? Files?

Comment: We need more context.  What is not working?  What is your error, etc.

Comment: delay the transition between the testimonials on main page.

Comment: www.urbandogex.com, don't know where to slow it down. As of now, the transition too fast, there i noway, visitors are able to read them.

Comment: Sorry I think Im the wrong threat, but maybe you can help me anyway. Here is my original question. Please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641812/slider-revolution-slider-can-anybody-help-me-please

Comment: You should mark the answer to this question if it helped you.