# How to change transition delay in a bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, revolution-slider

Im trying to slow down the transition in the testimonial slider on main page. Where would I do that? I tried to change in the css file, bootstrap, but it wouldn't do it. The problem I keep having is that when I change the transition, it does not do it "between" each transition. Here is the url: www.urbandogex.com. Any help is appreciated. Im trying to finish this site. I also would like the testimonial quotes (text) to be centered.

Thanks
Sasa

Comment: This question is pretty vague and is asking a lot.  Be sure to post code and follow these rules on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That does not really help me. I have done research, and am pretty new in this area which means I can't really know how and what to ask the right way. My question is, how do I change the speed between the 'running' testimonials in their slider. They are too fast to read. That is my question. url for the website issue is: www.urbandogex.com (index page)

Comment: There are probably hundreds of different types of sliders out there, so on Stack Overflow we need to see which one, and preferably the css and javascript code that you are using to implement the slider.  That way it will help others when they find this question.  Can you post the code or tell us how you implemented the slider?  Is this a wordpress site or did you use a website template?

Comment: http://revolution.themepunch.com/jquery/

Comment: I used a template btw, not WordPress, responsive html template

Comment: Which version of the rev slider you are using 4 or 5?

Comment: It looks like the version is 3.0.8 from the header of the jquery.themepunch.revolution.js file.  I wonder if you add a data attribute to each element's li tag like data-delay="3" for example

Answer (score 0):

The testimonials is not a revolution slider, it is a bootstrap carousel.  To change the interval for that, open up scripts.js and edit the `interval: 1500` value in the following:

```
/*******************************  carousel  ***********************************/

    $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 1500
        });
```

This is to change a Revolution Slider:  It looks like the theme you're using has an outdated version of the revolution slider (3.0.8) for which there isn't much documentation (if any) available.  This is just a guess, but you could try adding the following property to your `<li>` tags in your main html file:

`data-delay="15"` (for 15 second delay)

In your code, for a 15 second delay, try:

```
<!-- Slider -->
        <article class="bannercontainer" style="overflow: visible;">
            <div class="banner  revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive" id="revslider-765" style="height: 789px;">
                <ul style="display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-height: 800px;">                        
                    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-delay="15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 18; opacity: 1;">
                        <div class="slotholder"><img src="./Urban Dog Excursions, Issaquah, WA, Issaquah Highlands, Klahanie, Sammamish, Mirrormont, Tiger Mt., Tiger Mountain, dog walking, dog walker, dog walkers, pet sitter, pet sitting, dog sitting, cat sitting, pet transportation_files/slider01.jpg" alt="//" class="defaultimg" style="width: 1894px; height: 1263px; opacity: 0; position: relative;"></div>
                        <div class="caption lfb  tp-caption start" data-x="left" data-y="top" data-speed="800" data-start="300" data-easing="easeOutBack" style="font-size: 17px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; line-height: 24px; white-space: nowrap; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1; left: 347px; top: 849px; visibility: visible;">       
                            <p><span>Pet Sitting</span>With me your pet is treated like<br> family. Loving care, companionship, <br>and fun.</p>
                            <a href="http://www.urbandogex.com/services.html" class="">Services/Pricing</a>
                        </div>                                 
                    </li>

                    <li data-transition="3dcurtain-vertical" data-slotamount="1" data-delay="15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 18; opacity: 1; position: absolute;">
                        <div class="slotholder"><img src="./Urban Dog Excursions, Issaquah, WA, Issaquah Highlands, Klahanie, Sammamish, Mirrormont, Tiger Mt., Tiger Mountain, dog walking, dog walker, dog walkers, pet sitter, pet sitting, dog sitting, cat sitting, pet transportation_files/slider02.jpg" alt="//" class="defaultimg" style="width: 1894px; height: 1263px; opacity: 0;"></div>
                        <div class="caption lfb  tp-caption start" data-x="left" data-y="top" data-speed="800" data-start="400" data-easing="easeOutBack" style="font-size: 17px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; line-height: 24px; white-space: nowrap; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1; left: 347px; top: 849px; visibility: visible;">   
                            <p><span>Dog Walking</span> Make a difference in how your dog <br>feels about himself after a  <br>healthy daily walk.</p>
                            <a href="http://www.urbandogex.com/Services.html" class="">Services</a>
                        </div>  
                    </li> 

                    <li data-transition="papercut" data-slotamount="1" data-delay="15" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 20; opacity: 1; position: absolute; transform: scale(1, 1) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);">
                        <div class="slotholder"><img src="./Urban Dog Excursions, Issaquah, WA, Issaquah Highlands, Klahanie, Sammamish, Mirrormont, Tiger Mt., Tiger Mountain, dog walking, dog walker, dog walkers, pet sitter, pet sitting, dog sitting, cat sitting, pet transportation_files/slider03.jpg" alt="//" class="defaultimg" style="width: 1894px; height: 1263px; opacity: 1;"></div>
                        <div class="caption lfb  tp-caption start" data-x="left" data-y="top" data-speed="1000" data-start="500" data-easing="easeOutBack" style="top: 0px; font-size: 17px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; line-height: 24px; white-space: nowrap; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1; left: 347px; visibility: visible;">    
                            <p><span>Pet Taxi</span> I make sure your pet gets to <br>his appointments.</p>
                            <a href="http://www.urbandogex.com/Services.html" class="">Pet Taxi</a>
                        </div>                                    
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            <div class="tp-loader" style="display: none;"></div><div class="tp-bannertimer" style="visibility: hidden; width: 28.5169%; overflow: hidden;"></div></div>
        <div class="tp-bullets simplebullets round hidebullets" style="bottom: 20px; left: 50%; margin-left: -55px;"><div class="bullet first"></div><div class="bullet"></div><div class="bullet last"></div><div class="tpclear"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; margin-top: -20px; left: 20px;" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows default hidearrows"></div><div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; margin-top: -20px; right: 20px;" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows default hidearrows"></div></article>
        <!-- End Slider -->
```

If you update to the latest (5.0), you can change the delay property in the javascript where the slider is initialized in your html file:

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
   jQuery("#slider1").revolution({
      sliderType:"standard",
      sliderLayout:"auto",
      delay:9000, //<-- change this value (in milliseconds)
      navigation: {
          arrows:{enable:true}              
      },            
      gridwidth:1230,
      gridheight:720        
    });     
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: @version: 3.0.8 (06.08.2013)

Comment: Hi, so the issue was the testimonial section, which i believe are run in revolution slider as well Here is the code I am referring to. The transition between each testimonial quote. I want to slow it down. It starts with <!-- begin Our Reputation -->in the html code. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought I had it addressed clearly in the original question.

Comment: The testimonial isn't a revolution slider, it is a bootstrap carousel, that's why everyone is confused.  Check the answer I added what you need at the top, but keeping the rest for reference

Comment: No just script.js, search all your folders it's in there

Comment: so it will slow it down if I change it to 1500 from the higher number I had?

Comment: so when I search for the code you gave me in the scripts file it says it is not able to find it.

Comment: Figured it out thank you! Oh also, if I want to center this quote, where do I do that? Would appreciate help please. You guys have been very helpful, thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: Sure, make sure you mark this answer with the checkbox if it helped! Also, please post a new question if it is about centering text, that doesn't relate to a carousel transition delay.  You'll probably find what you need online already.

Comment: @user1804391 This might have helped you if you searched for it to begin with, just a heads up for next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147394/how-to-change-the-interval-time-on-bootstrap-carousel

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to search for the answers on here, but gave up as there are sooo many answers and searching is limited for someone who is 'green' in the area. Thank you for helping me, so what do you suggest I post if I want to center the quote text  in the bootstrap carousel on main page?

Comment: I would post the part of html code that shows what you want centered.

Comment: It says too many characters. Should I just try add it to my original question? Its the index page where it starts with our reputation and ends with end reputation line.